# XSLT 2.0: Flat XML to arbitrary hierarchical XML, if attribute = attribute then

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, hierarchy

I have an XML document with a flat hierarchy which must be transformed in an hierachical XML document:

At first an example of the XML source document:

```
<group id="xyz">
   <name>bla</name>
   <part id="abc1"><name>blabla-1</name></part>
   <part id="abc2"><name>blabla-2</name></part>
   <part id="abc3"><name>blabla-3</name></part>
   <part id="abc4"><name>blabla-4</name></part>
   <part id="abc5"><name>blabla-5</name></part>
   <part id="abc6"><name>blabla-6</name></part>
   <part id="abc7"><name>blabla-7</name></part>
   <part id="abc8"><name>blabla-8</name></part>
</group>
<group id="abc4">
   <name>blabla-4</name>
   <part id="abc9"><name>blabla-9</name></part>
   <part id="abc10"><name>blabla-10</name></part>
   <part id="abc11"><name>blabla-11</name></part>
   <part id="abc12"><name>blabla-12</name></part>
   <part id="abc13"><name>blabla-13</name></part>
   <part id="abc14"><name>blabla-14</name></part>
   <part id="abc15"><name>blabla-15</name></part>
   <part id="abc16"><name>blabla-16</name></part>
</group>
<group id="abc10">
   <name>blabla-10</name>
   <part id="abc17"><name>blabla-17</name></part>
   <part id="abc18"><name>blabla-18</name></part>
   <part id="abc19"><name>blabla-19</name></part>
   <part id="abc20"><name>blabla-20</name></part>
   <part id="abc21"><name>blabla-21</name></part>
   <part id="abc22"><name>blabla-22</name></part>
   <part id="abc23"><name>blabla-23</name></part>
   <part id="abc24"><name>blabla-24</name></part>
</group>
```

Here's an example how the targed XML document should look like:

```
<group id="xyz">
   <name>bla</name>
   <part id="abc1"><name>blabla-1</name></part>
   <part id="abc2"><name>blabla-2</name></part>
   <part id="abc3"><name>blabla-3</name></part>
   <group id=abc4">
      <name>blabla-4</name>
      <part id="abc9"><name>blabla-9</name></part>
         <group id="abc10">
         <name>blabla-10</name>
            <part id="abc17"><name>blabla-17</name></part>
            <part id="abc18"><name>blabla-18</name></part>
            <part id="abc19"><name>blabla-19</name></part>
            <part id="abc20"><name>blabla-20</name></part>
            <part id="abc21"><name>blabla-21</name></part>
            <part id="abc22"><name>blabla-22</name></part>
            <part id="abc23"><name>blabla-23</name></part>
            <part id="abc24"><name>blabla-24</name></part>
         </group>
      <part id="abc11"><name>blabla-11</name></part>  
      <part id="abc12"><name>blabla-12</name></part>
      <part id="abc13"><name>blabla-13</name></part>
      <part id="abc14"><name>blabla-14</name></part>
      <part id="abc15"><name>blabla-15</name></part>
      <part id="abc16"><name>blabla-16</name></part>
   </group>
</group>
```

Comment: Why are the `part` elements with id `abc5`, `abc6` and so on not in the result output of `group id="xyz"`? Do you want to stop processing `part` elements once a `part` referencing a `group` (like the `abc4`) is found?

Comment: Your first problem is that your "XML source document" isn't an XML document because it's missing a root-level element.

Comment: To Martin Honnen: Nope, I forgot to add abc5-abc8 to the example (shame on me!) It shouldn't stop process there... And to Ian Roberts: For the example I left out the root-document, the real document has a root-element, so again, my mistake -_- thanks for the answers so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply process any referenced groups with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:param name="start-id" as="xs:string" select="'xyz'"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="gid" match="group" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('gid', $start-id)"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="part[key('gid', @id)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="key('gid', @id)"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

then the result for the input

```
<groups>
<group id="xyz">
   <name>bla</name>
   <part id="abc1"><name>blabla-1</name></part>
   <part id="abc2"><name>blabla-2</name></part>
   <part id="abc3"><name>blabla-3</name></part>
   <part id="abc4"><name>blabla-4</name></part>
   <part id="abc5"><name>blabla-5</name></part>
   <part id="abc6"><name>blabla-6</name></part>
   <part id="abc7"><name>blabla-7</name></part>
   <part id="abc8"><name>blabla-8</name></part>
</group>
<group id="abc4">
   <name>blabla-4</name>
   <part id="abc9"><name>blabla-9</name></part>
   <part id="abc10"><name>blabla-10</name></part>
   <part id="abc11"><name>blabla-11</name></part>
   <part id="abc12"><name>blabla-12</name></part>
   <part id="abc13"><name>blabla-13</name></part>
   <part id="abc14"><name>blabla-14</name></part>
   <part id="abc15"><name>blabla-15</name></part>
   <part id="abc16"><name>blabla-16</name></part>
</group>
<group id="abc10">
   <name>blabla-10</name>
   <part id="abc17"><name>blabla-17</name></part>
   <part id="abc18"><name>blabla-18</name></part>
   <part id="abc19"><name>blabla-19</name></part>
   <part id="abc20"><name>blabla-20</name></part>
   <part id="abc21"><name>blabla-21</name></part>
   <part id="abc22"><name>blabla-22</name></part>
   <part id="abc23"><name>blabla-23</name></part>
   <part id="abc24"><name>blabla-24</name></part>
</group>
</groups>
```

is

```
<groups>
   <group id="xyz">
      <name>bla</name>
      <part id="abc1">
         <name>blabla-1</name>
      </part>
      <part id="abc2">
         <name>blabla-2</name>
      </part>
      <part id="abc3">
         <name>blabla-3</name>
      </part>
      <group id="abc4">
         <name>blabla-4</name>
         <part id="abc9">
            <name>blabla-9</name>
         </part>
         <group id="abc10">
            <name>blabla-10</name>
            <part id="abc17">
               <name>blabla-17</name>
            </part>
            <part id="abc18">
               <name>blabla-18</name>
            </part>
            <part id="abc19">
               <name>blabla-19</name>
            </part>
            <part id="abc20">
               <name>blabla-20</name>
            </part>
            <part id="abc21">
               <name>blabla-21</name>
            </part>
            <part id="abc22">
               <name>blabla-22</name>
            </part>
            <part id="abc23">
               <name>blabla-23</name>
            </part>
            <part id="abc24">
               <name>blabla-24</name>
            </part>
         </group>
         <part id="abc11">
            <name>blabla-11</name>
         </part>
         <part id="abc12">
            <name>blabla-12</name>
         </part>
         <part id="abc13">
            <name>blabla-13</name>
         </part>
         <part id="abc14">
            <name>blabla-14</name>
         </part>
         <part id="abc15">
            <name>blabla-15</name>
         </part>
         <part id="abc16">
            <name>blabla-16</name>
         </part>
      </group>
      <part id="abc5">
         <name>blabla-5</name>
      </part>
      <part id="abc6">
         <name>blabla-6</name>
      </part>
      <part id="abc7">
         <name>blabla-7</name>
      </part>
      <part id="abc8">
         <name>blabla-8</name>
      </part>
   </group>
</groups>
```

Comment: And if you don't have a specific group ID to start from you could process all "top-level" groups (i.e. those that are not cross-referenced by any `part`) by defining a second key `<xsl:key name="pid" match="part" use="@id"/>` and then make the initial `apply-templates select="group[not(key('pid', @id))]"`

Comment: @IanRoberts, I agree on your suggestion but will wait until the poster comments whether the whole approach does what is required.

Comment: Thank you guys for the answers. I will try this asap and give some feedback. First of all I'll try to retrace the script by Martin Honnen - this is actually what the result should look like. The hint by Ian Roberts is good. As it is a part list, there will be always a group with a specific ID that contains all following groups and parts. But I will keep the second key suggestion in mind and try it too - but first of all the proposed script, thanks alot Martin Honnen!

Comment: Ok, I modified the example and it works just fine, so thanks alot again. But just another question: Is this the muenchian grouping solution? With XSLT 2.0 you would rather to it with the group-by-function, right?

Comment: No, a key is used to efficiently follow the cross references in your input XML, that is not grouping. So in XSLT 1.0 or 2.0 or 3.0 I think the use of `key` is adequate. Muenchian grouping also uses a key but in a different way.

Comment: Okay - I came across the Muenchian grouping method before and thought this might be another usage of it, but if not that's even better.So thanks alot for your help!